# The global CKEDITOR_VERSION constant has already been set on vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am creating Vue spa and integrating CKEditor here using [this package](https://github.com/igorxut/vue-ckeditor5) I tried to do just like the tutorial by adding this to my app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'
import documentEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document'
import VueCkeditor from 'vue-ckeditor5'

const options = {
  editors: {
    classic: ClassicEditor,
    document: documentEditor
  },
  name: 'ckeditor'
}

Vue.use(VueCkeditor.plugin, options);
```

and to make it work I doing NPM install to those 2 editors (ClassicEditor and documentEditor)

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document
```

and since I also need CKEditor but with much more simpler or to being said without image upload features then I for the ckeditor5 build classic and remove those plugin from there and then NPM build and then I am doing this on my Vue spa

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
```

after that, I open @ckeditor folder on node_modules and find the ckeditor5-build-classic folder and replace build folder with my custom version of CKEditor build classic

but then I get this error

```
ckeditor-version-collision: The global CKEDITOR_VERSION constant has already been set.
```

even though the editor still working, but I don't like the idea my console showing error

Answer (score 1):

This problem is precisely described in [docs](https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html#scenario-3-using-two-different-editors), you can't run two editors from different builds on the same page (or mixing builds and source code).

tl;dr; The easiest way to enable running two different editors on the same site is to create a custom build that will export these two builds. This is described in the above docs.

The behavior has changed ~3 months ago and the error has been added to such situation to prevent bugs and big size of the bundle. Therefore the author of the https://github.com/igorxut/vue-ckeditor5 can just update the readme to follow the latest version's API.

Comment: oh, okay my only reason why i create 2 build is that i using ckeditor for 2 main places... one is for bloging which have all the ckeditor classic can do + table and the other is for company info where i don't want any image upload... and i don't find a way to just make this page have image upload and other page not having it.... or maybe i am missing out something?

Comment: You can follow the instructions from https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html#scenario-3-using-two-different-editors and add table plugin and image upload plugin only to the first editor. Then you could use both exported editors for two different cases while having the bundle size optimized.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to create ["super build"](https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html#creating-super-builds).

For example you can clone repository of [classic build](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic) and change 3 files.

Check my [gits](https://gist.github.com/igorxut/7958be654134b7475466ed3b85b7fbee).

I updated [example1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/igorxut/vue-ckeditor5/master/examples/example1/index.html) for using this [build](https://github.com/igorxut/vue-ckeditor5/tree/master/examples/custom-editors).